# Can gzip in a BASH script give an exit status before a file is completely unzipped? How to prevent this?

Tags: bash, gzip, exitstatus

I am trying to write a script to collect a few statistics on .fastq files sequentially. In my script, I unzip and re-zip each file in a loop (`gzip / gzip -d`), applying commands to find the stats on each file whilst it is unzipped using i.e. 
`command  "${file_name//.fastq.gz/.fastq}"` .

When I do this, my script sometimes fails to collect statistics for certain files, (e.g. giving me line counts of zero). However, it does this seemingly randomly and running the script more than once it sometimes collects stats and sometimes doesn't for the same file.

I believe this is because the gzip is returning an exit status before the file is fully unzipped, meaning that my script continues and sometimes collects stats from half-zipped files. In support of this, I have seen different stats for the file sizes returned for the same file (but not for stats like header line counts, which seem to be either zero or the values I would expect).

Is there a best way to tell BASH to wait until the file is completely unzipped? I have tried using variants of `until [ -f "${file_name//.fastq.gz/.fastq}" ]` and `until [ command "${file_name//.fastq.gz/.fastq}" != 0 ]` but I still don't always get the right results this way (I have checked by unzipping filesand applying each command manually), then comparing values to the script each time.

I've posted the script below and linked a picture showing output from two different runs of the script on four files to highlight the issue. For the record, I have been running this script on a sun grid engine and it has been returning no error messages to accompany this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -l h_rt=01:00:00
#$ -l h_vmem=1G
#$ -o fastq_qc_stats_job_out_file.txt
#$ -e fastq_qc_stats_job_error_file.txt

#First, make a file to store the output
if echo "${PWD}/" | grep -iq "/[a-Z]*_[0-9]*/"  # if in numbered batches (i.e. the data to be analysed is split across multiple numbered files)
then batch=`echo "${PWD}/" | grep -o "/[a-Z]*_[0-9]*/" |  cut -d '_' -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f 1` # get the batch number to name the output file,
else batch=`basename $PWD`; fi # otherwise just use the final part of the directory name.
header_line=`echo {'FILE','RUN','SIZE','READ_COUNT','MEAN_READ_LENGTH'} | sed 's/ /,/g'` # make a header line
echo $header_line > "QC_FASTQ_stats_${batch}.csv" # make a .csv file with the header line (by batch)
#Now loop through the FASTQ files and add the following information for each of them

for file in `ls *.fastq.gz`
do gzip -d $file # unzip the file
f="${file//.fastq.gz/.fastq}"
accession=`echo ${f} | cut -d '.' -f 1 | cut -d '_' -f 1`
filesize=`du -h ${f} | awk '{print $1}'`
readcount=`grep -E '^@[EDS]RR' ${f} | grep -E ' length=' | wc -l`
averagelength=`grep ' length=' ${f} | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk '{ total += $1 } END { print total/NR }'` # calculates mean
filestats=`echo $file $accession $filesize $readcount $averagelength | sed 's/ /,/g'`
echo $filestats >> "QC_FASTQ_stats_${batch}.csv" # add stats for each .fastq file to the .csv file
gzip ${f} # re-zip the file
done
```

[An example of the output variation when run twice for the same files - see 4th file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neVEV.png)

Comment: If you're having trouble with your script, it would be best to post your script and describe how it's not working correctly. See [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I don't see how gzip could return an error code, but then keep doing something. As noted in the previous comment, you'd need to provide your script, or better the minimum script you can come up with that has the issue.

Comment: I've added the script and a link to a picture that helps show the problem with the output. Sorry if my description is unclear but as you suggest, it's probably because I don't understand the real issue I'm having

Comment: `gzip -d` does not return until it's completely done. Thus, a script that runs it in the foreground *does not* proceed to future lines while `gzip` is still running.

Comment: BTW, why are you rezipping the file, instead of just leaving the original zipped copy in-place? `gunzip` doesn't *have* to delete your files, and you're running a lot less risk of inducing corruption if you don't do more rewrites than you need to.

Comment: Also, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: BTW, it'd be helpful if you could build a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* example, which can be run by others (without needing to have a bunch of .fastq files of their own!) to see the problem and thus verify potential fixes.

Comment: (BTW, you're running on a POSIX-compliant filesystem, right? Having a sufficiently broken filesystem -- say, one with a FUSE backend writing to S3 or similar -- is one way to get the behavior you're seeing, and it's occasionally known to happen in environments where folks are optimizing for performance / bulk storage over correctness)

Comment: To address previous comments:
1) okay, that's what I always thought
2) lack of experience - thanks for the heads up
3) thanks, I will
4) I'd love to but it would take me a long time to do and I have too many other bigger commitments right now. I might come back and do this when I have more time though. 
5) Honestly, I have no idea but I can look into it.